# $pull works on mongo shell but not in nodejs(expressjs) code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell, robo3t

The collection contains the following document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b02df7a45b504151cb42c40"),
"email" : "micro@gmail.com",
"appointments" : [ 
    {
        "patient_name" : "patient_1",
        "patient_id" : 1.0,
        "time" : 1528915447.0
    }, 
    {
        "patient_name" : "patient_2",
        "patient_id" : 2.0,
        "time" : 1529915447.0
    }
]}
```

The following operation will remove the document with patient_name= "patient_2" (i.e. the second document) when I tried it on robomongo tool or mongo shell

```
db.getCollection('doctors').update(
{ email: "micro@gmail.com" },
{ $pull: { appointments: {patient_name: "patient_2", patient_id:2, time: 1529915447} } } 
)
```

However, when the I tried the same thing with the node api, it just sent the response as `{success: true}` but didn't remove that particular document from the db

```
app.post('/secure/doctor/reject_appointment', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    if(!req.user){
        res.json({success: false,message:"Unauthorized"});;
    return;
    }
    Doctor.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id,
        {$pull: { appointments: {patient_name: req.body.patient_name, patient_id:req.body.patient_id, time: req.body.time}}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true},
        function(err, doc) {
            if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json({
                success:false
                }).end();
            }else{
                console.log(doc.appointments)
                res.json({
                success:true
                }).end();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

request body: `{ patient_name: 'patient_2', patient_id: 2, time: 1529915447 }` Can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Rather than just saying you checked it, how about showing what it actually contains here. You might be able to see what is there but we cannot. And even if you think it's okay, we might think differently and notice the problem that you don't. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50552739/edit)

Comment: Can you check the MongoDB version you are using?

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow it's 2.6.10

Comment: you should use `update` in node as well... and only one field `patient_id` can pull the object from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the MongoDB version and only single unique parameter can pull the data and your query will work: Also, keep NPM and Node update.

[Upgrade MongoDB version to 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/).

```
app.post('/secure/doctor/reject_appointment', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    if(!req.user){
        res.json({success: false,message:"Unauthorized"});;
    return;
    }
    Doctor.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id,
        {$pull: { appointments: {patient_id:req.body.patient_id}}},
        {safe: true, upsert: true},
        function(err, doc) {
            if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json({
                success:false
                }).end();
            }else{
                console.log(doc.appointments)
                res.json({
                success:true
                }).end();
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: $pull worked with multiple parameters as well.
Upgrading MongoDB and node versions solved the problem.
Thanks!